# Download HTML as separate pages

Tags: html, python-sphinx, read-the-docs

I'm using Read The Docs for a project. Everything seems to be working well online. However, when I download the HTML for offline use, I find that the documentation is all crammed into a single HTML file (index.html). Is it possible to download the documentation so that it has the same look and feel as the online docs with separate, linked pages?

I tried changing the documentation type from the RTD Admin > Settings page between the three options (Sphinx Html, Sphinx HtmlDir, and Sphinx Single Page HTML), but none of these seem to visibly change either the online content or the downloaded HTML structure.

[Python's documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/archives/python-3.5.0-docs-html.zip) from generated from Sphinx does have separate HTML files. Yet [Read The Docs's own documentation](https://readthedocs.org/projects/docs/downloads/htmlzip/latest/) also downloads as a single HTML file.

Am I missing something, or is this a limitation of Read The Docs?

- My Read The Docs site is here: http://kiva.readthedocs.org/en/docs/
- My GitHub Repository is here: https://github.com/nealkruis/kiva/tree/docs/docs

Comment: a link would be nice...

Comment: what the heck is Read The Docs? a dropbox?

Answer (score 3):

[HTTrack](https://www.httrack.com/) does a good job of mirroring Read the Docs:

```
httrack 'http://doc.scrapy.org/en/1.0/' -O scrapy-1.0
```

Answer (score 1):

Answer from ericholscher on #readthedocs IRC:

> correct, we build our downloadable HTML as a single page by default
>
> there's currently no setting to change that