# Display each section (h1, h2, h3) in a new page in Sphinx

Tags: python-sphinx

When I build HTML output using sphinx, it is possible to display h1 and h2 on separate pages, however, h3 is always displayed on the same page as h2. Does anyone know how to make sphinx display the content of h3 on a separate page? The same way traditional online help systems do this.

For example:

- Section

  - Sub-section
  - Sub-section

    - Sub-sub-section
    - Sub-sub-section
  - Sub-section

So, I want when I click on sub-sub-section see the content only under that sub-sub-section and not from Sub-section above or sub-sub-section below.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: There is no way to "chunk" an input file into multiple output files. Each input file (\*.rst) always corresponds to one output file (\*.html).

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, based on this note from the readthedocs.org irc channel one of the main devs said no, that's not possible.

Source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32788289/3750804

If you want this support the only thing I can suggest is checking out MkDocs at http://mkdocs.org, however, you lose PDF building capability and some other LaTex support that's included in Sphinx.

Good luck!

Comment: This answer seems to be about whether readthedocs supports download of multiple HTML pages. But the question (which is not tagged with "readthedocs") is about whether Sphinx supports "chunking" one RST file into multiple HTML files. These are two different things.

Answer (score -3):

So, we were able to make it work by adjusting the HTML template and the globaltoc setting.

Comment: Exactly how did you adjust the HTML template and the globaltoc setting?

Comment: I cannot share the details about the Jinja template settings that have been changed as it is confidential, but for the globaltoc., we set the value to 4.

Comment: I'm sorry to say this, but without much more details this answer is useless. It does not help anyone.

Comment: Well, can't you at least provide an outline of how adjusting the template and the globaltoc solved the problem?

Comment: What is the globaltoc setting? The only reference to globaltoc in the Sphinx documentation is the `globaltoc.html` template for the sidebar...