# Sphinx toctree, automodule all html in one page

Tags: python, html, python-sphinx, toctree

I am using Sphinx to document my Python project. My issue is all my python files under Table of Content, are listed under one page.

This is what I have so far. I would file to have Python_file_1,Python_file_2 and Python_file_3 in different html page. Beside them being under same page. Any suggestion or comment will be much appreciated!

```
    Welcome to Sphinx documentation!
=================================================================================

Contents:

.. toctree::
   :maxdepth: 6


.. automodule:: Python_file_1
.. autoclass:: Pyhon1_class
    :members:

.. automodule:: Python_file2

.. automodule:: Python_file_3
.. autoclass:: Python3_class
    :members:
```

Comment: If you want separate HTML pages, then you need to have separate RST pages. Sphinx cannot split one source file to several output files. See also http://stackoverflow.com/q/34098567/407651