# Display on index.html page just selected option from CONTENTS table (Sphinx library)

Tags: python-sphinx

I have got an issue by working with Sphinx library in Python.
When the user selects one option from the "CONTENTS:" table, all the files content is displayed on the content page.

[image]
As you can see, the scroll bar isn't at the beginning, but in the middle, which shows that the page contains previously another content.
How to configure Sphinx, so by selecting one submenu from "Contents" it's displaying just its content, not the whole available data (one page per option from Contents)?
Thank you very much in advance.

Update 1:
content of index.rst file
[image]

content of TestScriptsList.rst
[image]

Comment: If you want a separate HTML page for each section in the output, you need separate RST files.

Comment: @mzjn I don't need a separate html page for each section.  I need to display on content page just the selected module. For example page https://pywinauto.readthedocs.io/en/latest/, user selects an option from "CONTENTS" and just that one is displayed.

Comment: All your content is in one file, TestScriptsList.rst. To achieve what you want, you need to split that file into smaller files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All your content is in one file, TestScriptsList.rst. To get the wanted result, you need to split that file into smaller files. Sphinx has no way to "chunk" an input file into multiple output files. Each input file (*.rst) always corresponds to one output file (*.html).

Similar questions have been asked before, but the answers are a bit unclear. See [Display each section (h1, h2, h3) in a new page in Sphinx](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34098567/407651) and [Sphinx: split output html into smaller pages than input files](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34913006/407651).