# A way to make a Sphinx document subsection start a new page?

Tags: python-sphinx

I need a way to escape from Sphinx’s limitation that HTML output contains one and only one page per level-1 heading. For the sake of readability, some of my document’s content must be divided into pages at a lower heading level.

I’m considering whether I can do this by manipulating the table of contents in the left sidebar, as follows.

Suppose I have a document with this structure:

```
Little section
    A subsection
    Another subsection
Big section
    Level 2 in a big section
    Another level 2 in a big section
Another little section
```

Normally the document would have three pages beginning with the headings “Little section,” “Big section,” and “Another little section.” But I want two additional pages, beginning with the headings “Level 2 in a big section” and “Level 2 in another big section.” I would do this as follows.

Put each level-2 section in a separate reST file, which makes its initial heading a level-1 heading from Sphinx’s point of view.

Add the `:orphan:` option to each “level 2” reST file so that it doesn’t appear in the sidebar TOC automatically.

Manually add level-2 entries to the sidebar TOC under “Big section” which have the text “Level 2 in a big section” and “Another level 2 in a big section,” and link to the orphaned “level 2” files.

I’m asking whether this is possible because I saw the following statement on sphinx-doc.org [Directives page.](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/restructuredtext/directives.html/) I have put the relevant part in italics:

> You can also give a “hidden” option to the [toctree] directive, like
> this:
>
> ```
> .. toctree::
>    :hidden:
>
>    doc_1
>    doc_2
> ```
>
> This will still notify Sphinx of the document hierarchy, but not
> insert links into the document at the location of the directive –
> *this makes sense if you intend to insert these links yourself*, in a different style, or *in the HTML sidebar.*

This appears to say: Yes, what I propose is possible. But I can’t find a clue to how it’s done. Can anyone provide insight?

Comment: There is no built-in way to split a single input page (RST) into multiple output pages (HTML). Similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62299828/407651.

Comment: I know this is a difficult question, and I've been looking for different solutions in various places for months. With respect, though, it's completely different from 407651. That question asked how to make the browser display only part of an HTML page. I am asking how to relax Sphinx's rigid rule about where it starts generating a new page. /// In any case, I'd hope that if what I asked about is really impossible, someone will suggest other ways of achieving or approximating the same result.

Comment: Creating a Sphinx extension that does what you want may not be easy, but I don't think it is impossible.